# I just installed docker, but running "hello world" failed, it doesn't download image?

Tags: image, docker, download

I've just downloaded latest doc on my mac, and docker --version shows

```
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
```

No problem. Then I tried docker to run hello world, as the user guide:

```
$docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Well it doesn't automatically download the helloworld image for me, seems it met some errors. How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you `docker login` first?

Comment: @BMW You shouldn't need to log in to get a public image like `hello-world:latest` ...

Comment: Are you being a web proxy? You may need to configure proxy settings if so. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#proxy-configuration

Comment: Thanks, yes I found I should "docker pull" first, seems my docker doesn't automatically pull any image even for "hello-world". Thanks.